# Existence of a special pentagonal tiling

Tags: polygons, geometric-construction, tiling

Is there a [pentagonal tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling) composed of only one shape of pentagon so that each pentagon touches exactly 5 other pentagons?
Two pentagons are in touch if they share at least one common point.

Few examples:

Here each pentagon touches exactly 6 other pentagons:
[image]

Here each pentagon touches exactly 7 other pentagons:
[image]

Here each pentagon touches exactly 8 other pentagons:
[image]

Here each yellow pentagon touches 5 other pentagons, each pink pentagon touches 6 other pentagons and each blue pentagon touches 7 other pentagons:
[image]

I just can not find any tiling that there are only 5 touches per pentagon.

Maybe it is trivial question but I am not very familiar with tiling theory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If such a tiling existed, it would necessarily have to be edge-to-edge with $3$ pentagons at every vertex. The tiling's skeleton (the graph formed by the vertices and edges of contact) would therefore be a $3$-regular infinite planar graph with each face being of size $5$. But by Euler's formula, this should be a dodecahedron, which is not a tiling. Thus no such tiling exists.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. If it is not too difficult I have additional question - in the pictures we have examples of 6, 7, or 8 touches per pentagon. What is the upper limit? Is there tiling with 9 touches per pentagon.

Comment: Aren't all periodic pentagonal tilings classified? In which case it's a finite search (the infinite families have isomorphic edge-graphs)

Comment: @Dan Rust: I do not know whether they are all classified, I am not very experienced in this field of math. Also I did not insist on that the tiling must be periodic.

Comment: Rao showed that the list is complete fairly recently. https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/michael.rao/publi/penta.pdf

Comment: @Dan Rust: The tile says: "Exhaustive search of convex pentagons which tile the plane". But again I did not insist on the pentagons to be convex.

Comment: Right, but that's at least a good first place to look, so that you can potentially rule out convex tiles.

Comment: This is obvious for convex pentagons, but why must nonconvex pentagons surround themselves in this manner?

Comment: You could say the tiling exists, on the sphere.